# Chemical Name Matching in R

Tags: r, match, bioinformatics

[**UPDATED**]

**Problem**

I have two databases :

**1:**

```
1   Name: D-Tagatose 1,6-bisphosphate
2   Name: 1-Phosphatidyl-D-myo-inositol;: 1-Phosphatidyl-1D-myo-inositol;: 1-Phosphatidyl-    myo-inositol;: Phosphatidyl-1D-myo-inositol;: (3-Phosphatidyl)-1-D-inositol;: 1,2-Diacyl-sn-glycero-3-phosphoinositol;: Phosphatidylinositol
3   Name: Androstenedione;: Androst-4-ene-3,17-dione;: 4-Androstene-3,17-dione
4   Name: Spermine;: N,N'-Bis(3-aminopropyl)-1,4-butanediamine
5   Name: H+;: Hydron
```

**2:**

```
>  <NAME>    Benzaldehyde, 4-[(trimethylsilyl)oxy]-     >  <SYNONYMS>    Benzaldehyde, p-(trimethylsiloxy)-
>  <NAME>    Benzeneacetic acid, methyl ester           >  <SYNONYMS>    q qer
>  <NAME>    Cyclopropaneoctanoic acid, 2-[[2-[(2-ethylcyclopropyl)methyl]cyclopropyl]methyl]-, methyl ester    >  <SYNONYMS>    Methyl 8-[2-((2-[(2-ethylcyclopropyl)methyl]cyclopropyl)methyl)cyclopropyl]octanoate #
>  <NAME>    Mevalonic lactone, trimethylsilyl deriv.   >  <SYNONYMS>    Mevalonic lactone, trimethylsilyl
>  <NAME>    Benzeneacetic acid, phenylmethyl ester     >  <SYNONYMS>    Acetic acid, phenyl-, benzyl ester
```

**Desired output:**

Match the names or synonyms from database 2 with database 1 names. *We're talking about chemical compounds and because of that slight variation in the name of the compounds can happen.* That's why I used the linked online databases for matching also.

**Input for testing:**

See the excel files in the link. [Data](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g6e95b6ece8c18a9399936581097dddc0c6d0bf6d7)

### What I tried?

1. Matching only the names (You have to subtract the "Name " string from the name in db 1)
2. Matching partial names -> Obliviously not the best idea in chemical name matching.
3. Matching using the following databases)

   [ChEBI](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/chebi/)

   [NIST](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=U78998&Units=SI)

   [PubChem](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/)

**Small R inputs:**

**Input 1**

```
structure(c(">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", 
">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", 
">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", 
">  <NAME>", " Benzaldehyde, 4-[(trimethylsilyl)oxy]-", " Benzeneacetic acid, methyl ester", 
" Cyclopropaneoctanoic acid, 2-[[2-[(2-ethylcyclopropyl)methyl]cyclopropyl]methyl]-, methyl ester", 
" Mevalonic lactone, trimethylsilyl deriv.", " Benzeneacetic acid, phenylmethyl ester", 
" Butanoic acid, 3,3-dimethyl-, methyl ester", " Acetic acid, (4-(trifluoromethoxy)phenyl)methyl ester", 
" Phosphoramidothioic acid, O,S-dimethyl ester", " Octanoic acid, phenylmethyl ester", 
" Benzenepropanoic acid, methyl ester", " 2-Propenoic acid, 3-phenyl-, methyl ester", 
" Propanoic acid, 2-methyl-, phenylmethyl ester", " Acetic acid, (2,3-dichlorophenyl)methyl ester", 
" L-Methionine, methyl ester", " Butanoic acid, phenylmethyl ester", 
"<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", 
"<SYNONYMS>", ">  <SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", 
"<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", ">  <SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", 
" Benzaldehyde, p-(trimethylsiloxy)-", " Acetic acid, phenyl-, methyl ester", 
" Methyl 8-[2-((2-[(2-ethylcyclopropyl)methyl]cyclopropyl)methyl)cyclopropyl]octanoate #", 
" Mevalonic lactone, trimethylsilyl", " Acetic acid, phenyl-, benzyl ester", 
" Butyric acid, 3,3-dimethyl-, methyl ester", " NA", " Methamidophos", 
" Octanoic acid, benzyl ester", " Hydrocinnamic acid, methyl ester", 
" Cinnamic acid, methyl ester", " Isobutyric acid, benzyl ester", 
" NA", " Methyl 2-amino-4-(methylsulfanyl)butanoate #", " Butyric acid, benzyl ester"
), .Dim = c(15L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"), 
    c("NAME", NA, "NA.1", "NA.2")))
```

**Input 2**

```
structure(c("Name: 1-Phosphatidyl-D-myo-inositol;: 1-Phosphatidyl-1D-myo-inositol;: 1-Phosphatidyl-myo-inositol;: Phosphatidyl-1D-myo-inositol;: (3-Phosphatidyl)-1-D-inositol;: 1,2-Diacyl-sn-glycero-3-phosphoinositol;: Phosphatidylinositol", 
"Name: Androstenedione;: Androst-4-ene-3,17-dione;: 4-Androstene-3,17-dione", 
"Name: Spermine;: N,N'-Bis(3-aminopropyl)-1,4-butanediamine", 
"Name: H+;: Hydron", "Name: 3-Iodo-L-tyrosine", "Name: 3-Methoxytyramine", 
"Name: 3-Methoxy-4-hydroxyphenylacetaldehyde;: (4-Hydroxy-3-methoxyphenyl)acetaldehyde;: Homovanillin", 
"Name: L-Noradrenaline;: Noradrenaline;: Norepinephrine;: Arterenol;: 4-[(1R)-2-Amino-1-hydroxyethyl]-1,2-benzenediol", 
"Name: 3,4-Dihydroxymandelaldehyde;: 3,4-Dihydroxyphenylglycolaldehyde", 
"Name: L-Metanephrine", "Name: L-Adrenaline;: (R)-(-)-Adrenaline;: (R)-(-)-Epinephrine;: (R)-(-)-Epirenamine;: (R)-(-)-Adnephrine;: 4-[(1R)-1-Hydroxy-2-(methylamino)ethyl]-1,2-benzenediol", 
"Name: 3-Methoxy-4-hydroxyphenylglycolaldehyde", "Name: L-Normetanephrine", 
"Name: L-Dopachrome;: 2-L-Carboxy-2,3-dihydroindole-5,6-quinone", 
"Name: 5,6-Dihydroxyindole;: DHI"), .Dim = c(15L, 1L))
```

Comment: This will go easier if you give us the output of `dput( head( db1 ) )` and the same for `db2`. I think the nature of the data are quite precise and a solution might be quite localised. I wouldn't want to guess at the exact structure of your data. Make sure that there are names to match between the datasets.

Comment: I don't know if there are matches. There is a link with my data "Input testing". If the names doesn't match they can be still the same compounds, that is the problem.

Comment: I don't want to download your data and import it. I'd happily copy and paste into an R session. Here's a tip. Don't make people you'd like to answer *your* question do all the leg work. Make it easier for them.

Comment: Take a sample of row indices, say 10 of them that *do* match according to your criteria. Show the difference between the inputs and the desired output. IMHO you have not adequately described the problem at hand for at least me to be able to provide a robust solution. Sorry!

Comment: Great! I think it will really help to have the data available to copy and paste
!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want an R solution to this, try something like the below. I really think you need to tidy your input, particularly the fourth element of the second set. What I've put works only on the first name of each chemical. I'll leave it to you to work on the synonyms.

Not all of your chemical names appear to have entries in the chemspider database, you may have more luck with others. Catching those entries without names is an important part of the function, everything breaks without that.

You'll need to register with chemspider to get a token for the api. It is free to do so.

The example chemical names you have given don't appear to match between the two data sets, so df3 below won't contain any matches. I hope this helps.

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

token <- "your token here" # from chemspider profile
#url <- "http://www.chemspider.com/Search.asmx/AsyncSimpleSearch?query="
url <- "www.chemspider.com/Search.asmx/SimpleSearch?query="

chemCrawl <- function(chemname){ # Query chemspider with chemical names, return ids. 
  # df1[13] in particular seems to throw an error. Don't know why. 
  chem.id <-tryCatch(xmlValue(xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(
    getURL(paste(url, "\"", curlEscape(chemname), "\"" ,"&token=" ,
                 token, sep = ""))
  ))), error=function(err) { 
    "oops"} )
  return(chem.id)
}

df1 <- as.data.frame(structure(c(">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", 
            ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", 
            ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", ">  <NAME>", 
            ">  <NAME>", " Benzaldehyde, 4-[(trimethylsilyl)oxy]-", " Benzeneacetic acid, methyl ester", 
            " Cyclopropaneoctanoic acid, 2-[[2-[(2-ethylcyclopropyl)methyl]cyclopropyl]methyl]-, methyl ester", 
            " Mevalonic lactone, trimethylsilyl deriv.", " Benzeneacetic acid, phenylmethyl ester", 
            " Butanoic acid, 3,3-dimethyl-, methyl ester", " Acetic acid, (4-(trifluoromethoxy)phenyl)methyl ester", 
            " Phosphoramidothioic acid, O,S-dimethyl ester", " Octanoic acid, phenylmethyl ester", 
            " Benzenepropanoic acid, methyl ester", " 2-Propenoic acid, 3-phenyl-, methyl ester", 
            " Propanoic acid, 2-methyl-, phenylmethyl ester", " Acetic acid, (2,3-dichlorophenyl)methyl ester", 
            " L-Methionine, methyl ester", " Butanoic acid, phenylmethyl ester", 
            "<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", 
            "<SYNONYMS>", ">  <SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", 
            "<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", ">  <SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", "<SYNONYMS>", 
            " Benzaldehyde, p-(trimethylsiloxy)-", " Acetic acid, phenyl-, methyl ester", 
            " Methyl 8-[2-((2-[(2-ethylcyclopropyl)methyl]cyclopropyl)methyl)cyclopropyl]octanoate #", 
            " Mevalonic lactone, trimethylsilyl", " Acetic acid, phenyl-, benzyl ester", 
            " Butyric acid, 3,3-dimethyl-, methyl ester", " NA", " Methamidophos", 
            " Octanoic acid, benzyl ester", " Hydrocinnamic acid, methyl ester", 
            " Cinnamic acid, methyl ester", " Isobutyric acid, benzyl ester", 
            " NA", " Methyl 2-amino-4-(methylsulfanyl)butanoate #", " Butyric acid, benzyl ester"
), .Dim = c(15L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
                                         "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"), 
                                       c("NAME", NA, "NA.1", "NA.2"))))

names(df1) <-c("class1", "name", "class2", "synonym") 
df1$name <- as.character(df1$name)
df1[1,2] # there are leading spaces
df1$name <- sub(" ", "", df1$name) # lose the leading space
#details of chemspider search api: http://www.chemspider.com/Search.asmx

df1$chem.id <- lapply(df1$name, chemCrawl)
head(df1)

name2 <- structure(c("Name: 1-Phosphatidyl-D-myo-inositol;: 1-Phosphatidyl-1D-myo-inositol;: 1-Phosphatidyl-myo-inositol;: Phosphatidyl-1D-myo-inositol;: (3-Phosphatidyl)-1-D-inositol;: 1,2-Diacyl-sn-glycero-3-phosphoinositol;: Phosphatidylinositol", 
                   "Name: Androstenedione;: Androst-4-ene-3,17-dione;: 4-Androstene-3,17-dione", 
                   "Name: Spermine;: N,N'-Bis(3-aminopropyl)-1,4-butanediamine", 
                   "Name: H+;: Hydron", "Name: 3-Iodo-L-tyrosine", "Name: 3-Methoxytyramine", 
                   "Name: 3-Methoxy-4-hydroxyphenylacetaldehyde;: (4-Hydroxy-3-methoxyphenyl)acetaldehyde;: Homovanillin", 
                   "Name: L-Noradrenaline;: Noradrenaline;: Norepinephrine;: Arterenol;: 4-[(1R)-2-Amino-1-hydroxyethyl]-1,2-benzenediol", 
                   "Name: 3,4-Dihydroxymandelaldehyde;: 3,4-Dihydroxyphenylglycolaldehyde", 
                   "Name: L-Metanephrine", "Name: L-Adrenaline;: (R)-(-)-Adrenaline;: (R)-(-)-Epinephrine;: (R)-(-)-Epirenamine;: (R)-(-)-Adnephrine;: 4-[(1R)-1-Hydroxy-2-(methylamino)ethyl]-1,2-benzenediol", 
                   "Name: 3-Methoxy-4-hydroxyphenylglycolaldehyde", "Name: L-Normetanephrine", 
                   "Name: L-Dopachrome;: 2-L-Carboxy-2,3-dihydroindole-5,6-quinone", 
                   "Name: 5,6-Dihydroxyindole;: DHI"), .Dim = c(15L, 1L))

name2 <- sub("Name: ", "", name2)
name2 <- sub(";.+$", "", name2)
chem.id <- rep(NA, 15)
df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(name2, chem.id))
names(df2)[1] <- "name2"
df2$chem.id <- lapply(df2$name2, chemCrawl)
head(df2)
df1$chem.id <- as.character(df1$chem.id)
df2$chem.id <- as.character(df2$chem.id)
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "chem.id", all = TRUE)
df3
```

Comment: Sadly no names match in the two database. What Could the problem eventually a solution?

Comment: Well, if there are no chemicals that are the same between the two databases, how do you expect a match to work?
If your aim is to get a third data set which is a combination of all the chemicals in the first set **and** all the chemicals in the second, then that is a different question.

Comment: The problem is that I have chemicals that are modified (i did not know before) so the problem I published is solved by you're idea. So I consider this thread closed. Thank you again for the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an easy solution for problem. Working with smiles or inchi/inchikeys can be painful enough, and matching common or IUPAC names doesn’t make it easier.

You can check Pubchem PUG method for retrieving compounds by name:
https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug_rest/PUG_REST_Tutorial.html#_Toc338920590

Simple solution in Python (which should quite easy to implement in R) can like below:

I exported your data to plain text files:

input1.csv

---

```
Benzaldehyde, 4-[(trimethylsilyl)oxy]-; Benzaldehyde, p-(trimethylsiloxy)-
Benzeneacetic acid, methyl ester; Acetic acid, phenyl-, methyl ester
Cyclopropaneoctanoic acid, 2-[[2-[(2-ethylcyclopropyl)methyl]cyclopropyl]methyl]-, methyl ester; Methyl 8-[2-((2-[(2-ethylcyclopropyl)methyl]cyclopropyl)methyl)cyclopropyl]octanoate #
Mevalonic lactone, trimethylsilyl deriv.; Mevalonic lactone, trimethylsilyl
Benzeneacetic acid, phenylmethyl ester; Acetic acid, phenyl-, benzyl ester
Butanoic acid, 3,3-dimethyl-, methyl ester; Butyric acid, 3,3-dimethyl-, methyl ester
Acetic acid, (4-(trifluoromethoxy)phenyl)methyl ester; NA
Phosphoramidothioic acid, O,S-dimethyl ester; Methamidophos
Octanoic acid, phenylmethyl ester; Octanoic acid, benzyl ester
Benzenepropanoic acid, methyl ester; Hydrocinnamic acid, methyl ester
2-Propenoic acid, 3-phenyl-, methyl ester; Cinnamic acid, methyl ester
Propanoic acid, 2-methyl-, phenylmethyl ester; Isobutyric acid, benzyl ester
Acetic acid, (2,3-dichlorophenyl)methyl ester; NA
L-Methionine, methyl ester; Methyl 2-amino-4-(methylsulfanyl)butanoate #
Butanoic acid, phenylmethyl ester; Butyric acid, benzyl ester
```

input2.csv:

```
Name: 1-Phosphatidyl-D-myo-inositol;: 1-Phosphatidyl-1D-myo-inositol;: 1-Phosphatidyl-myo-inositol;: Phosphatidyl-1D-myo-inositol;: (3-Phosphatidyl)-1-D-inositol;: 1,2-Diacyl-sn-glycero-3-phosphoinositol;: Phosphatidylinositol
Name: Androstenedione;: Androst-4-ene-3,17-dione;: 4-Androstene-3,17-dione
Name: Spermine;: N,N'-Bis(3-aminopropyl)-1,4-butanediamine
Name: H+;: Hydron
Name: 3-Iodo-L-tyrosine
Name: 3-Methoxytyramine
Name: 3-Methoxy-4-hydroxyphenylacetaldehyde;: (4-Hydroxy-3-methoxyphenyl)acetaldehyde;: Homovanillin
Name: L-Noradrenaline;: Noradrenaline;: Norepinephrine;: Arterenol;: 4-[(1R)-2-Amino-1-hydroxyethyl]-1,2-benzenediol
Name: 3,4-Dihydroxymandelaldehyde;: 3,4-Dihydroxyphenylglycolaldehyde
Name: L-Metanephrine
Name: L-Adrenaline;: (R)-(-)-Adrenaline;: (R)-(-)-Epinephrine;: (R)-(-)-Epirenamine;: (R)-(-)-Adnephrine;: 4-[(1R)-1-Hydroxy-2-(methylamino)ethyl]-1,2-benzenediol
Name: 3-Methoxy-4-hydroxyphenylglycolaldehyde
Name: L-Normetanephrine
Name: L-Dopachrome;: 2-L-Carboxy-2,3-dihydroindole-5,6-quinone
Name: 5,6-Dihydroxyindole;: DHI
```

Python code:

```
import requests

def name_to_cids(name):
    '''Retrive set of pubchem cids for given name'''
    url = 'https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/name/{0}/cids/JSON'.format(name)
    r = requests.get(url)
    return set(r.json()["IdentifierList"]["CID"])  if r.status_code == 200 else set()


def names_to_cids(names):
    '''Take list of names and return set of pubchem cids'''
    cids = set()
    for name in names:
        cids = cids.union(name_to_cids(name))
    return cids

def find_matching(from_key, from_dict, to_dict):
    matching = []
    from_cids = from_dict[from_key]['cids']
    for k, v in to_dict.items():
        if len(from_cids.intersection(v['cids'])) != 0:
            matching.append(k)
    return matching

#Read input files
input_1 = [line.replace('#','').strip().split(';') for line in open('input1.csv').readlines()]
input_2 = [[n for n in line.replace('Name: ', '').strip().split(';:') if n != 'NA'] for line in open('input2.csv').readlines()]

input_1_dict = {" ".join(names): {'names': names, 'cids': names_to_cids(names)} for names in input_1}
input_2_dict = {" ".join(names): {'names': names, 'cids': names_to_cids(names)} for names in input_2}

print(find_matching(from_key=input_1_dict.keys()[0], from_dict=input_1_dict, to_dict=input_2_dict))
```

Pubchem won't handle well modifications (for example you can find cids for Benzeneacetic acid but not for Benzeneacetic acid, methyl ester) so depending on your needs you may consider removing some part of query string (i.e. search for  Benzeneacetic acid instead of Benzeneacetic acid, methyl ester) but i understand it far from good.

**Update**

You can also try something more sophisticated.

- At the beginning I would try to identify what category of records do you have (common name, IUPAC name).
- for each name you can try to retrieve chemical structure using correct service (Pubchem, ChEBI) or software like OPSIN (https://bitbucket.org/dan2097/opsin) depending on name/identifier category
- compute pairwise tanimoto similarity between molecules using software of your choice.
- based on tanimoto coefficients identify entries you are looking for.

Comment: I can't really remove anything from the database. Specially now what you mentioned. I have around 4000 core compounds and were checked by name once to fit the task that they're needed for. I appreciate you're quick response I try it out but I still wait for other responses also.

Comment: I've posted an update with another idea how to deal with your data. If you won't find a better solution you can consider going in that direction.